In-place construction and perfect forwarding
Perfect forwarding is used to construct objects in place. So, I expect, that no copy or move constructors will be called. But the following code does not compile. Compiler says it needs move constructor.
Why?
Is it possible to construct this object in-place inside vector or some other class?
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class nonmovable_t {
   public:
    nonmovable_t(int) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; };
    nonmovable_t(const nonmovable_t&) = delete;
    nonmovable_t(nonmovable_t&&) =delete;
    nonmovable_t& operator=(const nonmovable_t&) = delete;
};


int main() {
    std::vector <nonmovable_t> v;
    v.emplace_back(nonmovable_t{1});
    return 0;
};



How does it not compile? The verbatim error must be provided with the question.

This is a rare use case for std::list which is a lot more compatible with unmoveable types than other sequential containers. However, the more typical solution is to wrap your non-moveable type in a smart pointer (std::vector<std::unique_ptr<nonmovable>>) or in a PImpl class.

v.emplace_back(nonmovable_t{1}) this is not in-place construction, this an attempt to in-place move construct.


Why?

Vector has some memory. Then you increase number of elements, so it allocates new memory with more spaces. Then vector has to move elements from old smaller memory to new bigger one. It needs a move constructor.

Is it possible to construct this object in-place inside vector or some other class?

Sure, use v.emplace_back(1);.
Irrelevant of constructing the object in-place inside the vector, you still have to un-delete the move constructor of your class to compile  with emplace_back at all, becuase the memory might be moved.

Are you sure v.emplace_back(1); would work if v is a std::vector<nonmovable_t>?  Doesn't increasing the size of a vector demand that it's value type is copyable or movable?

With a non-movable element type only the constructor of std::vector can be used to create elements. All the modifiers, including emplace_back, won't be available.

"use v.emplace_back(1);"  No, that won't compile.

@DrewDormann I do not understand your comment. Yes, it won't compile - the currently presented code by OP is in contradiction with the requirements of std::vector::emplace_back, which I hope I outlined in the first paragraph of the answer. If you want to see that the code compiles, you have to edit the class definition not to delete the move constructor. Do you think my answer requires an edit? Sorry, I do not udnerstand the purpose  of comments. I added another sentence to make it more clear. Kindly review.

@KamilCuk your answer includes "Is it possible? ... Sure, use v.emplace_back(1);"  That seems to be an incorrect statement.  It is not possible to construct that object using std::vector::emplace_back.  Unless am am misunderstanding you.


Compiler says it needs move constructor. Why?

std::vector::emplace_back will resize a vector, and all vector resizing operations require their elements to be either copyable or movable.
So it is correct that you are not allowed to emplace_back to a vector of elements that can not be copied or moved.

Is it possible to construct this object in-place inside vector or some other class?

Yes.  You could use the constructor taking a size_type, but your type would need to become default-constructible.
class nonmovable_t {
   public:
    nonmovable_t() : nonmovable_t{0} { }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Adding default constructor

    nonmovable_t(int) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
    nonmovable_t(const nonmovable_t&) = delete;
    nonmovable_t(nonmovable_t&&) = delete;
    nonmovable_t& operator=(const nonmovable_t&) = delete;
};


int main() {
    std::vector <nonmovable_t> v( 1 ); // The 1 means "vector size of 1"
    return 0;
};

